# How to remove Root tag and keep rest all row tags in an xml using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've the below XML file.

```
<root>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>45.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>46.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
</root>
```

I want to create another XML by eliminating the  tag. So, my new XML will look like -

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>45.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>46.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Below is my code and I'm able to generate byte class by eliminating the  and keeping all the necessary row tags. but finally not able to convert my byte class to an xml format and getting the below error :

xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 11, column 0

Can you please assist?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

base_tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
catalog = list(base_tree.getroot())
elemList = []
for elem in catalog:
  getele = ET.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
  elemList.append(getele)

byt = b''.join(elemList)
print(byt)

mytree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(byt))
dis = str(ET.tostring(mytree.getroot()), 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Your "new XML" is not well-formed XML. XML requires a root element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getchildren) for this.

```
with open('input.xml') as input_file:
    text = input_file.read()
    catalog = list(ET.fromstring(text))[0]
    ET.tostring(catalog, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
```

Though resulting string will not be a valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

root element is mandatory for being XML.

For just text processing maybe we could just do

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("<[/]{0,1}root>")
removed = re.sub(pattern, '', "<root>something</root>");

print(removed)
```

?

Comment: But then how will you solve the second problem ?
 http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247  :). I would avoid regex when I have some structure like XML.